# Moodle - Password verification

Tags: moodle

I want to be able to create the admin user during the site installation with only 6 normal characters instead :

> Passwords must be at least 8 characters long.
>   Passwords must have at least 1 digit(s).
>   Passwords must have at least 1 upper case letter(s).
>   Passwords must have at least 1 non-alphanumeric character(s).

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to change the Password policy at:

Settings > Site administration > Security > Site policies

Check this [documentation](https://docs.moodle.org/28/en/Site_policies#Password_policy) for details and instructions. Hope it helps.

Comment: Is there any way I could change it during the site installation ? When I'm asked to add the first user ?

Comment: Not sure exactly, but since during installation you are required to create the admin user (assuming your admin doesn't count as "first user"), that gives you access to change through the Administration. Also, during installation, Moodle generates a configuration file within the moodle directory called config.php, you can try to see if there is something related there.